# Не работает mergeProps в компоненте на react+redux?-

Tags: reactjs, redux

Используется reactjs+redux.

Требуется получить доступ к хранилищу из метода компонента mapDispathToProps

Вроде как общепринятая практика в этой ситуации(поскольку напрямую состояние из этого метода не доступно) является использование метода mergeProps

[статья на хабре](https://habr.com/post/314582/)

Но этот способ не взлетает, что я делаю не так?

mapDispatchToProps в котором мне требуется state:

```
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    load: () => dispatch(actions.loadProjects()),
  };
}
```

после преобразования в метод mergeProps стал выглядеть так:

```
function mergeProps(stateProps, dispatchProps) {
  const {dispatch} = dispatchProps;

  return {
    load: () => dispatch(actions.loadProjects()),
  };
}
```

соответственно, перешел от

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ViewComponent);
```

к

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mergeProps)(ViewComponent);
```

Answer (score 0):

reducer:

```
export default function(state = null, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'SET_DATA':
            return action.data;
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

Функция для получения данных из стора

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        data: state.data
    }
};
```

Функция для записи данных в стор:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        setData: (params) => dispatch(params)
    }
};
```

Добавляем эти функции через коннект:

```
export default compose(
    connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)
)(MyComponent)
```

Вот так будет выглядеть добавление данных в стор:

```
const data = {
   type: 'SET_DATA',
   data: {id: 1, value: "value"}
};
this.props.setData(data);
```

А то, что вытащим из стора будет доступно как `this.props.data`